# How to add child components after deleting all child components?

Tags: python, user-interface, python-3.x, tkinter

Currently, I'm preforming the following code to delete the child widgets on the gui

`for child in infoFrame.winfo_children():
    child.destroy()`

However, the gui will not add another child to the gui. For example, neither lines of the following code

`people.place(in_ = gui, x = 1, y = 1, width = 422, height = 449)`

`people.grid(row = 0, column = 0)`

place a label on the gui. I'm using the following code to create the label

`people = Label(text = "Default", fg = "black", bg = "white")`

**EDIT** I was asked to add my gui code, so here it is:

```
def initializeGui(name = "Default"):
    GUI = Tk()
    GUI.geometry("423x450+200+200")
    GUI.title(name)
    return GUI

def buttonAnswers(): #This is what I'm focusing on
    gui.title("Answers")
    for child in gui.winfo_children():
        child.destroy()
    return True
    people = Label(text = "Default", fg = "black", bg = "white")
    #people.place(in_ = gui, x = 1, y = 1, width = 422, height = 449)
    people.grid(row = 0, column = 0)

def buttonTest(): #This will be the same as the button above but will open a different gui
    gui.title("Test")
    for child in gui.winfo_children():
        child.destroy()
    return True

    question = Label(text = "Do you want to see the Answers or take the Test?", fg = "black", bg = "white")
    question.grid(row = 0, column = 1)
    checkAns = Button(gui, text = "Answers", command = buttonAnswers, fg = "black", width=10)
    checkAns.grid(row = 1, column = 0)    

gui = initializeGui("School Test")
label = Label(text = "Do you want to see the Answers or take the Test?", fg = "black", bg = "white")
label.grid(row = 0, column = 1)
answers = Button(gui, text = "Answers", command = buttonAnswers, fg = "black", width=10)
questions = Button(gui, text = "Test", command = buttonTest, fg = "black", width=10)
answers.grid(row = 1, column = 0)
questions.grid(row = 1, column = 2)`
```

---

The solution to the issue was the following:

```
def buttonAnswers(): #This is what I'm focusing on
    gui.title("Answers")
    for child in gui.winfo_children():
        child.destroy()
    return True
    people = Label(text = "Default", fg = "black", bg = "white")
    #people.place(in_ = gui, x = 1, y = 1, width = 422, height = 449)
    people.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
```

contained a `return True` underneath the for loop, preventing the program from continuing. As such, removing the `return True` allowed the program to continue with the script and add the other children to the form.

```
def buttonAnswers(): #This is what I'm focusing on
    gui.title("Answers")
    for child in gui.winfo_children():
        child.destroy()
    people = Label(text = "Default", fg = "black", bg = "white")
    #people.place(in_ = gui, x = 1, y = 1, width = 422, height = 449)
    people.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
```

Comment: You're going to need to show us an actual, working program. Assuming the new `people` object actually exists, and assuming the `gui` object actually exists, your code will work fine. When you say neither of the lines place the label, do you get an error, or is the area where the widget should be simply blank?

Comment: Bryan, without the `for child in infoFrame.winfo_children():
    child.destroy()` the code for the label does work and gets placed on the gui however, with it, the label does not place on the gui. I'll edit the question to contain my gui code.

Comment: Remember that `winfo_children` will get the _children_, which is not always the same as the list of widgets packed/gridded _in_ the frame. I notice you're using `in_`, so make sure you're getting the correct list of widgets and not deleting more widgets than you think you are.

Comment: thanks bryan, I'll check what widgets it's grabbing

Comment: @BryanOakley, when I print out the children of the gui, I'm given this `[<tkinter.Label object at 0x02A540D0>, <tkinter.Button object at 0x02CC4EF0>, <tkinter.Button object at 0x02CC4ED0>]`
Any idea why deleting these 3 widgets would prevent me from adding anything else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a return statement after you destroy the widgets but before you add any new widgets. The code to add the new widgets is never getting executed.

Comment: what do you mean a return statement? How would I go about doing that?

--EDIT--
Ah, just saw what you meant. Thanks for noticing Bryan!